# Xamarin Forms - Difference Between ICommand and Command?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, icommand

In Xamarin Forms MVVM projects, I've seen both:

`public ICommand MyCommand {...}`

and

`public Command MyCommand {...}`

What is the difference between the two, and when should I use which? Could I replace all `ICommand`'s with `Command`'s with no ill effect?

Comment: They both basically provide the same functionality. The first one `ICommand` allows for more custom implementations of the interface while the second forces the implementations to have at least a base of `Commad`. The framework is happy once it inherits from `ICommand`.

Comment: You should read about interfaces and how they get implemented.  Also, the concept of polymorphism in object oriented programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two, and when should I use which?

They both basically provide the same functionality. The first one `ICommand` allows for more custom implementations of the interface while the second defines an `ICommand` implementation that wraps a `Action`. It forces the implementations to have at least a base of `Command` and also provides a starting point if you don't want to roll your own implementation of `ICommand`.

> Could I replace all `ICommand`'s with `Command`'s with no ill effect?

The framework is happy once what you use inherits from `ICommand`.

```cs
ICommand command = new Command (() => Debug.WriteLine ("Command executed"));
var button = new Button {
  Text = "Hit me to execute the command",
  Command = command,
};
```